# How to validate an url on the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, url

In an iPhone app I am developing, there is a setting in which you can enter a URL, because of form & function this URL needs to be validated online as well as offline.

So far I haven't been able to find any method to validate the url, so the question is;

How do I validate an URL input on the iPhone (Objective-C) online as well as offline?

Comment: Read the comments to his answer, the validation does not work correctly.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c), you can avoid using RegexKit.
Here is my solution (works for iphone development with iOS > 3.0) :

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

If you want to check in Swift my solution given below:

```
 func isValidUrl(url: String) -> Bool {
        let urlRegEx = "^(https?://)?(www\\.)?([-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*?[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z]{2,6}(/[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?&/=%]*)?$"
        let urlTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)
        let result = urlTest.evaluate(with: url)
        return result
    }
```

Comment: This only works for urls of type "http://www.webr.ly" does not work for urls with parameters like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqgExtdNMBk

Comment: `((http|https)://)?((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+"` .It should make http:// or https:// is optiional.

Comment: not working for google.com, www.google.com and also for //www.google.com

Comment: following urls are not working in my case.                                             
http://money.cnn.com/2015/10/19/technology/apple-app-store/index.html?category=home

Comment: @DJtiwari +1 yes it's not working did you find any fix for that?

Comment: http://52.88.111.0/API/public/uploads/facilities/images/2585/f6873da52827bbbd-1.png. Not working in my case

Comment: this is not working for more complex url's or fails to get invalid url's like in the comments above shown

Comment: All this goes through: `www.ailive` `wwwailive.` I'm not even including `com` or any extentions.!!! ???????

Answer (score 239):

Why not instead simply rely on `Foundation.framework`?

That does the job and does not require `RegexKit` :

```
NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:candidate];
// WARNING > "test" is an URL according to RFCs, being just a path
// so you still should check scheme and all other NSURL attributes you need
if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host) {
  // candidate is a well-formed url with:
  //  - a scheme (like http://)
  //  - a host (like stackoverflow.com)
}
```

According to Apple documentation :

> **URLWithString:** Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a
>   provided string.
>
> `+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `URLString` : The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must conform to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. ***If the string was malformed, returns nil.***

Comment: You have a small typo.  Should be `... and candidateURL.host`.  Nice solution.

Comment: +1. This is much better than a regex, for the simple reason that a regex is fragile and adds complexity. An `NSURL` instance is either valid or `nil`, yielding a quick, simple yes/no answer about the validity of the URL.

Comment: I agree with some of the others here. This is a much better solution that fiddling around with regular expressions. This should be the correctly checked answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't prevent all malformed urls from being returned as nil

Comment: @MrThys - Any chance you could provide examples of which malformed urls this doesn't catch?  Would be great to know.. seems an excellent solution so far.

Comment: @DonamiteIsTnt The URL `http://www.aol.comhttp://www.nytimes.com` passes this test.

Comment: The code will not check for malformed url. Ex: <code>http://afasd</code>, the url will still pass the test

Comment: The docs are wrong. Write a few tests — `NSURL` does not return nil when I pass a string of @"#@#@$##%$#$#", or @"tp:/fdfdfsfdsf". So this method will be useless for checking valid HTTP URLs and the like.

Comment: If I enter URL like : "file://localhost/...", is it valid?

Comment: Unfortunately hashtags get turned into NSURLs by this API. As an example "#hashtag" becomes an NSURL.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has so many upvotes. This method accepts an empty string as a valid URL.

Comment: unfortunately it will return as valid a nil hostname as http://(null)...elegant solution but won't validate even the most basic scenarios.

Comment: this seems to work for the test cases @TonyArnold pointed out (iOS 9.1 SDK) but fails for www.microsoft.com because the host is nil. if i do http//www.microsoft.com or http:// microsoft.com, it passes the validation. For an average Joe, www.microsoft.com is a proper url so in my case I've to tweak this solution. Edit: add a ' ' after http:// because SO automatically hyperlinks it.

Comment: @newDeveloper if you add http:// to tp:/fdfdfsfdsf - it passes... check -rocode- answer in the bottom - i think its the best over here.

Comment: Not sure where all the upvotes are coming from, but simple check: https://123.123.123.123qwe:6001 passes this validation. Quite invalid ;)

Answer (score 32):

Instead of writing your own regular expressions, rely on Apple's. I have been using a category on [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) that uses [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to test for the presence of a link within a string. If the range of the link found by `NSDataDetector` equals the length of the entire string, then it is a valid URL.

```
- (BOOL)isValidURL {
    NSUInteger length = [self length];
    // Empty strings should return NO
    if (length > 0) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDataDetector *dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];
        if (dataDetector && !error) {
            NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
            NSRange notFoundRange = (NSRange){NSNotFound, 0};
            NSRange linkRange = [dataDetector rangeOfFirstMatchInString:self options:0 range:range];
            if (!NSEqualRanges(notFoundRange, linkRange) && NSEqualRanges(range, linkRange)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Could not create link data detector: %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Extremely clever. Real engineering.  {You know, I had a weird problem where if I send it the string literally "<null>", it crashes! Could never figure it out.}

Comment: Ah - it was "<null>" in the son, which apple usefully supplies as an NSNull!  :O

Comment: I created a gist where I started adding test cases for this snipped. Fill free to add more. https://gist.github.com/b35097bad451c59e23b1.git

Answer (score 26):

My solution with **Swift**:

```
func validateUrl (stringURL : NSString) -> Bool {

    var urlRegEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[urlRegEx])
    var urlTest = NSPredicate.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(predicate)

    return predicate.evaluateWithObject(stringURL)
}
```

For Test:

```
var boolean1 = validateUrl("http.s://www.gmail.com")
var boolean2 = validateUrl("https:.//gmailcom")
var boolean3 = validateUrl("https://gmail.me.")
var boolean4 = validateUrl("https://www.gmail.me.com.com.com.com")
var boolean6 = validateUrl("http:/./ww-w.wowone.com")
var boolean7 = validateUrl("http://.www.wowone")
var boolean8 = validateUrl("http://www.wow-one.com")
var boolean9 = validateUrl("http://www.wow_one.com")
var boolean10 = validateUrl("http://.")
var boolean11 = validateUrl("http://")
var boolean12 = validateUrl("http://k")
```

Results:

```
false
false
false
true
false
false
true
true
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 10):

use this-

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"http(s)?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?";
```

Comment: i copied it simply for asp.net regular expression validator ;)

Comment: perfect, the only problem is that it doesn't recognize `www.google.com/+gplusname`

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem using [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net), and build a quick regex to validate a URL;

```
NSString *regexString = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
NSString *subjectString = brandLink.text;
NSString *matchedString = [subjectString stringByMatching:regexString];
```

Then I check if the matchedString is equal to the subjectString and if that is the case the url is valid :)

Correct me if my regex is wrong ;)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe that regex doesn't validate urls with query strings or named anchors.

Comment: You could make the prefix part optional by replacing (http|https):// with ((http|https)://)* but this would allow a very wide variety of urls

Answer (score 4):

Oddly enough, I didn't really find a solution here that was very simple, yet still did an okay job for handling `http` / `https` links.

Keep in mind, THIS IS NOT a perfect solution, but it worked for the cases below. In summary, the regex tests whether the URL starts with `http://` or `https://`, then checks for at least 1 character, then checks for a dot, and then again checks for at least 1 character. No spaces allowed.

```
+ (BOOL)validateLink:(NSString *)link
{
    NSString *regex = @"(?i)(http|https)(:\\/\\/)([^ .]+)(\\.)([^ \n]+)";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    return [predicate evaluateWithObject:link];
}
```

Tested VALID against these URLs:

```
@"HTTP://FOO.COM",
@"HTTPS://FOO.COM",
@"http://foo.com/blah_blah",
@"http://foo.com/blah_blah/",
@"http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)",
@"http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)_(again)",
@"http://www.example.com/wpstyle/?p=364",
@"https://www.example.com/foo/?bar=baz&inga=42&quux",
@"http://✪df.ws/123",
@"http://userid:password@example.com:8080",
@"http://userid:password@example.com:8080/",
@"http://userid@example.com",
@"http://userid@example.com/",
@"http://userid@example.com:8080",
@"http://userid@example.com:8080/",
@"http://userid:password@example.com",
@"http://userid:password@example.com/",
@"http://142.42.1.1/",
@"http://142.42.1.1:8080/",
@"http://➡.ws/䨹",
@"http://⌘.ws",
@"http://⌘.ws/",
@"http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-",
@"http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-",
@"http://foo.com/unicode_(✪)_in_parens",
@"http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens",
@"http://☺.damowmow.com/",
@"http://code.google.com/events/#&product=browser",
@"http://j.mp",
@"http://foo.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff",
@"http://مثال.إختبار",
@"http://例子.测试",
@"http://उदाहरण.परीक्षा",
@"http://-.~_!$&'()*+,;=:%40:80%2f::::::@example.com",
@"http://1337.net",
@"http://a.b-c.de",
@"http://223.255.255.254"
```

Tested INVALID against these URLs:

```
@"",
@"foo",
@"ftp://foo.com",
@"ftp://foo.com",
@"http://..",
@"http://..",
@"http://../",
@"//",
@"///",
@"http://##/",
@"http://.www.foo.bar./",
@"rdar://1234",
@"http://foo.bar?q=Spaces should be encoded",
@"http:// shouldfail.com",
@":// should fail"
```

Source of URLs:
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if you do not want `http` or `https` or `www`

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"^(http(s)?://)?((www)?\.)?[\w]+\.[\w]+";
```

example

```
- (void) testUrl:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", ([self isValidUrl:urlString] ? @"VALID" : @"INVALID"), urlString);
}

- (void)doTestUrls{
    [self testUrl:@"google"];
    [self testUrl:@"google.de"];
    [self testUrl:@"www.google.de"];
    [self testUrl:@"http://www.google.de"];
    [self testUrl:@"http://google.de"];
}
```

Output:

```
INVALID: google
VALID: google.de
VALID: www.google.de
VALID: http://www.google.de
VALID: http://google.de
```

Comment: This seems very interesting. Is it 100% bullet proof?

Answer (score 3):

Lefakir's solution has one issue.
His regex can't match with "http://instagram.com/p/4Mz3dTJ-ra/".
Url component has combined numerical and literal character. His regex fail such urls.

Here is my improvement.

```
"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+)+(/)?(\\?.*)?"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found the easiest way to do this is like so:

```
- (BOOL)validateUrl: (NSURL *)candidate
{
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:candidate];
    return [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req];
}
```

Comment: I've been using it for a while now and it seems to work fine. It also seems to play nice with the new TLDs (https://www.namecheap.com/domains/new-tlds/explore.aspx).

Comment: This is pointless. If your URL is invalid string, it will crash while creating a `NSURL`, so that could checked instead of this. And even so it uses old API.

Comment: @Legoless could just use a try...catch around it?

Comment: @Legoless Which version do you work on? This solution works well in my situation.

Comment: This test considers `http://` and `https://` to be valid (i.e. scheme without host).  It accepts the `file://` scheme which might not be what you want if you are wanting to validate that it is a web url.  Conversely, it does not accept the `tel://` and `facetime://` schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Below code will let you find the valid URLs

```
      NSPredicate *websitePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",@"^(((((h|H)(t|T){2}(p|P)s?)|((f|F)(t|T)(p|P)))://(w{3}.)?)|(w{3}.))[A-Za-z0-9]+(.[A-Za-z0-9-:;\?#_]+)+"];
     if ([websitePredicate evaluateWithObject:##MY_STRING##])
     {
       printf"Valid"
     }
```

for such URLS

- http://123.com
- https://123.com
- http://www.123.com
- https://www.123.com
- ftp://123.com
- ftp://www.123.com
- 
- 
- www.something.com

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer is incorrect.
I have an URL with an "-" in it, and the validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

Tweeked Vaibhav's answer to support G+ links:

`NSString *urlRegEx = @"http(s)?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w-\\+ ./?%&amp;=]*)?";`

Answer (score 1):

Some URL's without / at the end are not detected as the correct one in the solutions above. So this might be helpful.

```
  extension String {
    func isValidURL() -> Bool{
        let length:Int = self.characters.count
        var err:NSError?
        var dataDetector:NSDataDetector? = NSDataDetector()
        do{
            dataDetector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
        }catch{
            err = error as NSError
        }
        if dataDetector != nil{
            let range = NSMakeRange(0, length)
            let notFoundRange = NSRange(location: NSNotFound, length: 0)
            let linkRange = dataDetector?.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: range)
            if !NSEqualRanges(notFoundRange, linkRange!) && NSEqualRanges(range, linkRange!){
                return true
            }
        }else{
            print("Could not create link data detector: \(err?.localizedDescription): \(err?.userInfo)")
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## URL Validation in Swift

### Details

Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3

### Code

> enum URLSchemes: String

```
import Foundation

enum URLSchemes: String {
    case http = "http://", https = "https://", ftp = "ftp://", unknown = "unknown://"

    static func detectScheme(urlString: String) -> URLSchemes {

        if URLSchemes.isSchemeCorrect(urlString: urlString, scheme: .http) {
            return .http
        }
        if URLSchemes.isSchemeCorrect(urlString: urlString, scheme: .https) {
            return .https
        }
        if URLSchemes.isSchemeCorrect(urlString: urlString, scheme: .ftp) {
            return .ftp
        }
        return .unknown
    }

    static func getAllSchemes(separetedBy separator: String) -> String {
        return "\(URLSchemes.http.rawValue)\(separator)\(URLSchemes.https.rawValue)\(separator)\(URLSchemes.ftp.rawValue)"
    }

    private static func isSchemeCorrect(urlString: String, scheme: URLSchemes) -> Bool {
        if urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: scheme.rawValue, with: "") == urlString {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

> extension String

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    var isUrl: Bool {

        // for http://regexr.com checking
        // (?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:xn--)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[#-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?

        let schemes = URLSchemes.getAllSchemes(separetedBy: "|").replacingOccurrences(of: "://", with: "")
        let regex = "(?:(?:\(schemes)):\\/\\/)(?:xn--)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\\.254(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\\.168(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[#-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?"


        let regularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.characters.count)
        let matches = regularExpression.matches(in: self, options: [], range: range)
        for match in matches {
            if range.location == match.range.location && range.length == match.range.length {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    var toURL: URL? {

        let urlChecker: (String)->(URL?) = { url_string in
            if url_string.isUrl, let url = URL(string: url_string) {
                return url
            }
            return nil
        }

        if !contains(".") {
            return nil
        }

        if let url = urlChecker(self) {
            return url
        }

        let scheme = URLSchemes.detectScheme(urlString: self)
        if scheme == .unknown {
            let newEncodedString = URLSchemes.http.rawValue + self
            if let url = urlChecker(newEncodedString) {
                return url
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
 func tests() {

    chekUrl(urlString:"http://example.com")
    chekUrl(urlString:"https://example.com")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://example.com/dir/file.php?var=moo")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://xn--h1aehhjhg.xn--d1acj3b")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://www.example.com/wpstyle/?p=364")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://-.~_!$&'()*+,;=:%40:80%2f::::::@example.com")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://example.com")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://xn--d1acpjx3f.xn--p1ai")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://xn--74h.damowmow.com/")
    chekUrl(urlString:"ftp://example.com:129/myfiles")
    chekUrl(urlString:"ftp://user:pass@site.com:21/file/dir")
    chekUrl(urlString:"ftp://ftp.example.com:2828/asdah%20asdah.gif")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://142.42.1.1:8080/")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://142.42.1.1/")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://userid:password@example.com:8080")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://userid@example.com")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://userid@example.com:8080")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens")

    print("\n----------------------------------------------\n")

    chekUrl(urlString:".")
    chekUrl(urlString:" ")
    chekUrl(urlString:"")
    chekUrl(urlString:"-/:;()₽&@.,?!'{}[];'<>+_)(*#^%$")
    chekUrl(urlString:"localhost")
    chekUrl(urlString:"yandex.")
    chekUrl(urlString:"коряга")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http:///a")
    chekUrl(urlString:"ftps://foo.bar/")
    chekUrl(urlString:"rdar://1234")
    chekUrl(urlString:"h://test")
    chekUrl(urlString:":// should fail")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://-error-.invalid/")
    chekUrl(urlString:"http://.www.example.com/")
}

func chekUrl(urlString: String) {
    var result = ""
    if urlString.isUrl {
        result += "url: "
    } else {
        result += "not url: "
    }
    result += "\"\(urlString)\""
    print(result)
}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)validateUrlString:(NSString*)urlString
{
    if (!urlString)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];

    NSRange urlStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [urlString length]);
    NSMatchingOptions matchingOptions = 0;

    if (1 != [linkDetector numberOfMatchesInString:urlString options:matchingOptions range:urlStringRange])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSTextCheckingResult *checkingResult = [linkDetector firstMatchInString:urlString options:matchingOptions range:urlStringRange];

    return checkingResult.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink && NSEqualRanges(checkingResult.range, urlStringRange);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to check if what the user entered is a URL? It can be as simple as a regular expression, for example checking if the string contain `www.` (this is the way that yahoo messenger checks if the user status is a link or not)
Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

Selfishly, I would suggest using a [`KSURLFormatter`](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities/blob/master/KSURLFormatter.h) instance to both validate input, and convert it to something `NSURL` can handle.

Comment: Is there an iOS flavour of this?

Comment: It should work just fine on iOS. If it doesn't, fix it up and send me a pull request, or file an issue

Answer (score 0):

I have created inherited class of UITextField which can handle all kind of validation using regex string. In this you just need to give them all the regex string in sequence and their message that you want to show when validation get failed. You can check my blog for more info, it will really help you

http://dhawaldawar.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/uitextfield-validation-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Anthony's answer to swift, I wrote a category on `String` which returns an optional `NSURL`. The return value is `nil` if the `String` can not be validated to be a URL.

```
import Foundation

// A private global detector variable which can be reused.
private let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)

extension String {
  func URL() -> NSURL? {
    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
    guard let URLResult = detector.firstMatchInString(self, options: [], range: textRange) else {
      return nil
    }

    // This checks that the whole string is the detected URL. In case
    // you don't have such a requirement, you can remove this code
    // and return the URL from URLResult.
    guard NSEqualRanges(URLResult.range, textRange) else {
      return nil
    }

    return NSURL(string: self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkValidUrl(_ strUrl: String) -> Bool {
    let urlRegEx: String = "(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+"
    let urlTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)
    return urlTest.evaluate(with: strUrl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Swift 5:

```
extension String {
    func isValidUrl() -> Bool {
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            // check if the string has link inside
            return detector.numberOfMatches(in: self, options: [], range: .init( location: 0, length: utf16.count)) > 0
        } catch {
            print("Error during NSDatadetector initialization \(error)" )
        }
        return false
    }
}
```