# How to determine if a string is a URL in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iPhone development and Objective-C. Using the ZBar SDK I've developed a basic app which scans a QR image from the photo album and outputs what it translates to.

I want to know if there is a way to take this output, determine whether it is a URL and if so open it in a web browser.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

NSURL's URLWithString returns nil if the URL passed is not valid. So, you can just check the return value to determine if the URL is valid.

**UPDATE**

Just using `URLWithString:` will usually not be enough, you probably also want to check if the url has a scheme and a host, otherwise, urls such as `al:/dsfhkgdsk` will pass the test.

So you probably want to do something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString];
if (url && url.scheme && url.host)
{
   //the url looks ok, do something with it
   NSLog(@"%@ is a valid URL", yourUrlString);
}
```

If you only want to accept http URLs you may want to add `[url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) Got it sorted now, need a lot more practice with Objective C though! haha

Comment: It seems to have a loose definition what's a valid URL. "foo.com" will parse so you probably want to check that the resulting object has a scheme property.

Comment: you can't just trust URLWithString, because NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"a"]; will return a to you. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone

Comment: However, you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) if you want to use regex instead.

Comment: I mean this " you can just check the return value to determine if the URL is valid." statement is not enough.

Comment: Is it OK to skip the `host` check if we also accept local file URLs?

Comment: you should check the `length` of the scheme since string "a" returns an empty string for it's scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution which I came across. You can do like this.

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourstring"]];
bool valid = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req];
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650542/2513947

Answer (score -1):

You can look at below code to check whether a string contains website url or simple text.

```
 NSString *getString =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"searchKey"];
    if([getString rangeOfString:@"Www"].location == NSNotFound
       && [getString rangeOfString:@"www"].location == NSNotFound && [getString rangeOfString:@"com"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [companyNameTF setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"searchKey"]];
    }
    else
    {
         [websiteTF setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"searchKey"]];
    }
```

Comment: This works in very limited cases. I.e. only urls that include `www` and `com`, which is by no means all of them. It only works if you know what to expect the URL to look like.