# Sanitize NSURL in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, react-native, xss, deep-linking, nsurl

I am using checkmarx for security vulnerabilities in code. (react-native). I enabled deep linking in react-native using this guide from the official documentation for ios https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking. From the documentation i added this code to AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

However checkmarx reports that i need to sanitize or validate the url to prevent XSS attacks, any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: The `url` will be `nil` if it is not valid. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811996/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-url-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Joshua what is the exact vulnerability that Checkmarx reports?

Comment: @RomanCanlas XSS vulnerability

Comment: @Joshua Asare there are at least 2 types of XSS under Objective C that Checkmarx have, can you be specific?

Comment: @Josh have you got any luck to resolved issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate the XSS vulnerability in the code, you must URL encode the url argument by using the [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc) method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{

NSString *urlEncoded = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:urlEncoded options:options];
}
```