# Recognize URL in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

Is it possible to recognize an url in xCode ? 
I'm trying to create an if statement, followed by opening the url.

I can't find anything about this on the internet, I've also tried searching for recognizing the first letters (like "http, file, www");

With kind regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString class has a method `rangeOfStrig:`

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.someurl.com";
if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"www"].location != NSNotFound ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: How do I use this ? Because if I don't have a http in the string it still goes to that line.

Comment: if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"www"].location != NSNotFound || [urlString rangeOfString:@"http"].location != NSNotFound )

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't works. It doesn't recognizes the www or http..

Comment: It works, i've tried the else if, this doesn't work so now I'm just using ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to check for the patterns you want (www, http, https, etc)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And here is a great regex http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm

And here is an example from stackoverflow, [How to validate an url on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone)