# AFNetworking - Invalid parameter not satisfying: url

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I just tried AFNetworking on ios7 and i get this error:

```
    /Classes/AFHTTPClient.m:227
 2013-09-16 18:25:57.557 App[13531:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: url
```

I don't know what's going on, is there an issue with the lib an ios7 ?
thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling with this problem now too. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I commented the line 227 : //    NSParameterAssert(url);
And it works..

Comment: It would help if you included the code where the program is erroring out. But, you should check if you are passing nil in the URL parameter like: `[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil]`. The NSParameterAssert(url) is in there to prevent against initializing the HTTP client with a nil URL.

Comment: @JamieForrest: Eventually I found out that the predefined settings from the Settings.bundle weren't read properly that's why my url was not filled at all. I assumed it was because I defined a default value, but sadly it didn't work. Just make a breakpoint and print the value of your URL there.

Comment: @arlg: That's a very stupid solution. The only thing that NSParameterAssert does is checking if the parameter is actually, and correctly, set. So I strongly discourage this solution!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Leon says in his comment, commenting out `NSParameterAssert` is not an ideal solution. An assertion has been put there for a reason by the author of `AFNetworking`. The code not passing the assertion is likely to be caused by an invalid URL.

Remember that the `NSURL` factory methods (that is, `+ URLWithString:` and its siblings) will return `nil` when they're passed an invalid URL string. In this context, an invalid string is a string containing an invalid URL.

What you should do instead of commenting our the assertion, is making sure that you are not passing any invalid URL's to your `AFHTTPClient` instance. [This Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819561/847174) gives an example of how you could validate a URL. Here's a sample from the answer:

```
- (BOOL)validateUrl:(NSString *)candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Alternatively, you could add percentage escapes using `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method. Like this:

```
NSString *encoded = [notEncoded stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I know It wasn't an ideal solution, but I needed a quick fix.
I can't try your answer right now because I'm not working on the project anymore. Anyway, Thanks for the answer, I will try it when I'll work again on the project :).

Comment: In my case, it turns out I had inadvertently added space at the beginning of the url string. So, yeah, this was mostly about misformed url.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this error, the cause was a space at the start of the url:

```
 http://host.com/etc
^
```

Answer (score 2):

as Kasper says --> "You could add percentage escapes using NSString's stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method"

or better use the following since it deprecated in ios 9

```
path = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird case today with this assert. My problem was that I have copied url from other text editor (Sublime) and that's why url was invalid.

I was not believing until I have tested it few times.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its Working.. In AFnetworing class name AFURLRequestSerialization.m

```
commented the line 227 : // NSParameterAssert(url);
```