# URL validation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my Swift iOS project, I want to check whether is the valid url or not before requesting to server. I did earlier in Objective C code to check many elements like presence of www, http, https, :, etc to validate whether the right url or not. Do we have anything similar in Swift code?

I am expecting like this Obj C method.

```
 - (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What did you do before? Did you try doing the same thing?

Comment: I tried to use NSPredicate predicateWithFormat, but couldn't be achieved in Swift.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24207852/3411787

Comment: Hi, I need to validate for this URL -> h t t p://192.168.1.146:8081/Myservelet/WebserviceA/?username=stella

Comment: Please temember to tick answers that solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4.x**

This Covers all types of validation like Subdomain, with or without HTTP / HTTPS

```
func isValidUrl(url: String) -> Bool {
    let urlRegEx = "^(https?://)?(www\\.)?([-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*?[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z]{2,6}(/[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?&/=%]*)?$"
    let urlTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)
    let result = urlTest.evaluate(with: url)
    return result
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Tested this code with Swift 5, unfortunately `stackoverflow.com.com` returns `true`, while `129.0.0.1` and `ftp://129.0.0.1` return `false.`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) to replace any special characters your link may have and then you can check if your link is a valid url using [NSURL(string:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:) as follow:

```
let link =  "http://www.yourUrl.com".stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: link) {
    // you can use checkedUrl here
}
```

Note: NSURL(string:) is only for weblinks. If you would like to create a NSURL for a local resource file you need to use NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)

Comment: You probably want to explain the rationale

Comment: @Wain What's to explain? NSURL already does the checking and only returns an instance if a valid string was given to it. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I didn't say reinvent the wheel, just describe why it works, so basically your comment in the answer. +1 anyway but the explanation adds value.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
func validateUrl (urlString: String?) -> Bool {
    let urlRegEx = "(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluateWithObject(urlString)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far seem to involve regex, which seems potentially error prone (easy to miss something on our end). Another option is just creating the url object, and leaving the validation to the Foundation framework.

```
func validateURL(urlString: String) -> Bool {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    return url.host != nil && url.scheme != nil /* and whatever other checks you want */
}
```

If the `URL` couldn't be parsed, the `host`, `scheme`, etc. will be `nil`.

Comment: Your answer did worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: The scheme will not be nil even for abc://abc.com so this solution is not validating HTTP or https

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5

As none of the above solutions worked for me in Swift 5, I ended up writing my own REGEX for swift 5. This covers all types of validation including PORT

```
func validateURL(url: String) -> Bool {
        let regex = "http[s]?://(([^/:.[:space:]]+(.[^/:.[:space:]]+)*)|([0-9](.[0-9]{3})))(:[0-9]+)?((/[^?#[:space:]]+)([^#[:space:]]+)?(#.+)?)?"
        let test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        let result = test.evaluate(with: url)
        return result
 }
```

Comment: This indeed works with ports (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/test`) but only if the URL starts with "http" or "https" (it fails for e.g. `http://---`, which shouldn't be valid). It doesn't work with e.g. `stackoverflow.com` or `www.stackoverflow.com`, even though they are both valid. I tried to replace the beginning (`http[s]?://`) with `((http|https|ftp)://)?` but then even `---`is valid, while e.g. `127.0..0.1` isn't (which is correct).

Answer (score 2):

this simple extension make life easy

```
extension String {
    var isValidUrl: Bool {
        let urlRegEx = "((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluate(with: self)
}
```

}

Comment: This one fails: https://res.mycloud.com/thor.gif.  But this regex is much better than others mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem with the highest rated answer here. I think it is plain wrong for two reasons:

**First**, the `stringByAddingPercentExcapedUsingEncoding` will actually *double* encode valid URLs, thus making them invalid or at least different than the original input. If the input string is already a correctly encoded URL then you should just use that.

For example, `http://foo.com/My%20Stuff/` will become `http://foo.com/My%2520Stuff/` which is not the same. If you feed that to NSURL, it will actually decode it to a URL with a literal `%` in it.

**Second**, `NSURL` is known to be very bad at recognizing bad input. For example it happily returns an non-nil result when you give it something like `x/3:()foo/blah` which is clearly malformed and not a valid URL.

I think it is best to use a regular expression. I don't think there is anything in *Foundation* that can properly validate URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this is pretty easy to swift

```
func validateUrl() -> Bool {
  let urlRegEx = "((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+"
  return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluate(with: self)
}
```

I find this easy. If you put as an extension or just in the class you can say

```
func fooBar(textField: UITextField) {   
   if textField == someTextField {
      if textField.text?.validateUrl() == true {
         print("true")
      } else {
         print("false")
      }
   }
}
```

Very similar to other answers tho, and years late

This doesn't require the http part, I feel like most users wouldn't bother typing in the http or https like http://www.google.com but instead just google.com or www.google.com

Obviously you could go the extra mile and check if they did or did not put the http(s) and if you really want to add it add it yourself..or not

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 5.0**

```
func validateUrl (urlString: String?) -> Bool {
        let urlRegEx = "(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluate(with: urlString)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expression like this. The pattern below is correct for url.

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/",options: nil, error: nil)!

if regex.firstMatchInString(searchTerm!, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, searchTerm!.length)) != nil {
    println("not valid url ")
}
```

Comment: Is this compiling properly? It is not compiling this code.  Build error in the 1st line - "Consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by ;"

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution. In Swift 3

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension String {

    var canOpenURL : Bool {

        guard let url = NSURL(string: self) else {return false}
        if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {return false}
        let regEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[regEx])
        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

It can be used as

```
if textField == someTextField {

    if (self.textField.text?.canOpenURL)! {
        //URL valid
    }else {
       //URL invalid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private var cancellbleSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

 func validateUrl1() {
    $url1
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .dropFirst()
        .sink { [self] in
            if $0 != "" {
                let pattern = "^(https?://)?(www\\.)?([-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*?[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z]{2,6}(/[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?&/=%]*)?$"
                let regex : Regex  = pattern.r!
                if regex.matches($0) {
                    isUrl1Valid = true
                } else {
                    isUrl1Valid = false
                }
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellbleSet)
}
```

Then you can call it inside the view model init, like this

```
 override init() {
    super.init()
    validateUrl1()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use *Regex* to validate URL Format

```
(https?://(www.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}.[a-z]{2,6}b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)
```

**SWIFT 4:**

```
func validateURL (urlString: String) -> Bool {
    let urlRegEx = "(https?://(www.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}.[a-z]{2,6}b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)"
    let urlTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)
    return urlTest.evaluate(with: urlString)
}
```