# Check if link pressed in UIWebView

Tags: swift, url, uiwebview, nsurl

I have a `UIWebView` which is set the URL like this:

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

However I'd like to be able to check if the user as pressed a link.

I tried something simple like this:

```
if (url != "http://google.com") {
            println("Do Stuff");
        }
```

which worked fine, however this only checks it in the `viewDidLoad` I'd like to now every time a link is pressed or when the URL changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the URL with making an custom function

```
func validateUrl (stringURL : NSString) -> Bool {

    var urlRegEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[urlRegEx])
    var urlTest = NSPredicate.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(predicate)

    return predicate.evaluateWithObject(stringURL)
}
```

It will return true or false. That is Bool

for example :

```
if (validateUrl("http://google.com")) {
    //will return true
    println("Do Stuff");
}
else
{
    //If it is false then do stuff here.
}
```

Call this function in

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if (validateUrl(request.URL().absoluteString())) {
        //if will return true
        println("Do Stuff");
    }
}
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207852/3202193

Comment: Where should I call for the function? I'm always used to call a function thru an IBAction etc, so this is kinda new for me :)