# What is correct way of validate the URL string and loading it in WKWEBVIEW based on responses with status code like 200... in IOS Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, url, wkwebview, mobile-website

I have Strings like https://www.google.com,htpps://www.tempalate-name1 and need to validate those strings are valid or not, loading it in wkwebview and validating it based on responses with status code like 200... rather than just validating the format of the URL string before loading in a wkwebview bypassing the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an url on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone)

Comment: hi, I am asking is their piece of the code snippet to validate the URL string by loading it in wkwebview and validating it based on responses with status code like 200...  rather than just validating the format of the URL string