# How to validate an email id in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

I need to validate an email address which was in the format  dsfdsf@.fdsf.com

As I am new I dont know how to validate the email address.

Please suggest me how to get out of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for validating email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practice-for-validating-email-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you will find the answer :-) 
[What are best practices for validating email addresses in Objective-C for iOS 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practice-for-validating-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

Same way you validate it in any language:  examine the string directly, use a regex, etc.

Do some google searches on email validation first though.  You'll find it's an area that's incredibly difficult to get right.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:userMailTextField.text] == YES)           
{
   //---- Code for action do you want
}
else
{
   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Email id is not in proper format" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
   [alert show];
}
```