# How to validate email field in uitextfield in iphone

Tags: iphone

i would like to check that whether the field entered in the text field is email or not.If its email field then proceed else show some alert or error.
I don't know how to validate that field.
Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for validating email address in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add `RegexKit` to your project.
Import `RegexKitLite.h` to the class where you want to check the format

```
NSString *emailMatchstring=@"\\b([a-zA-Z0-9%_.+\\-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\\b";
```

compare this string to `UITextField`'s text.

Comment: Thanks Sherry but the regular expression you have written is missing something its showing some warnings.I did it with this way without using the RegexKit,Bcoz i downloaded the kit from somewhere ,but some files were missing in that.Here is the simple way which also checks if the letters are capital                                                             NSString *emailRegE=@"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?";

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular expression can help you.

[NSRegularExpression Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708)