# Email Validation iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, validation, email

Assuming I have created `IBOutlet UITextField *emailValidate;`

And the empty method

```
-(IBAction)checkEmail:(id)sender {

// Add email validation code here.

}
```

And linked the File Owner file to the `TextField`, what code would I have to insert in the method to validate an email adress? checking that only one '@' is included, and only one '.' is included?

Comment: Which of the three '.' characters in `graham.lee@example.co.uk` is the one that is allowed?

Comment: only one `.`? are you implying the millions of firstName.lastName@provider.tld are not valid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for validating email address in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 17):

Use the function below...

```
+(BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) email 
{
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
BOOL isValid = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I use a regex found at [this blogpost](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/verifying-that-string-is-email-address.html):

```
NSString *emailRegEx =
    @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if there is exactly one "@" by splitting the string on '@' and checking for 2 pieces.

```
int numberOfAtPieces = [[emailValidate.text  componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count];
if ( numberOfAtPicess != 2 ) {  // show error alert }
else {  // let it through }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get set of code from the following  [link](http://erfan-ali-31.blogspot.in/2011/09/email-address-validation-in-text-field.html?showComment=1347539827005#c2615295578881941696) . Hope this may helpful

Answer (score 0):

I've used the solution shared by Macarse (the big regexp) for a few weeks with success, but I suddenly ran into a problematic case. It does not pass the test with "test1_iPhone@neywen.net" for instance. 
So I chose to go back to the simpler solution provided by S P Varma (the small and simple regexp).

Answer (score -1):

You could call the following method on the text of the UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Please adapt the emailRegex regular expression to your needs.

Comment: I hope you upvoted catlan for this ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c/1149894#1149894

Comment: That regex will not work: it will strip out a lot of valid e-mails.