# how to displat alertmessage while enter text in textfiled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, validation, uitextfield

hi i am new iphone developer.my problem is i do one app ie user registration form in that form(username,password,email) and add these textfield values to array to displat on tableview and take one button when i enter data in textfields and click that button another view display and all user data display on tableview i write code for that but my problem is with out enter data in textfield and click button display alertview but i don't how to validate email textfield while enter data in textfield,please help to i want to display message  while enter data in email textfield(alertmsg-enter email aaa@gmail.com formate like)

Answer (score 1):

For empty text field you can use following method :

```
-(BOOL) emptyCheck:(NSString *)textFieldtext
{
    return [[textFieldtext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]count]<=0;
}
```

for email you can use `NSRegularExpression` class and specify regEx format for email.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this [What are best practices for validating email addresses in Objective-C for iOS 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c) , 
hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwing code for email validation:-

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        //Valid email address
        if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == YES) 
        {
}
else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"E-Mail Field Not In proper Format"  message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

        }
```