# Validate Email address Using Regex

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am Trying to validate email address field using below regex

```
    + (BOOL) isValidEmail:(NSString *)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

But its getting failed for validating below cases.

i) test@-gmail.com

ii) test..test@gmail.com

iii) .test@gmail.com

iv) test.@gmail.com

Please suggest me what modification do I need for considering these cases.

Comment: that will also fail with unicode TLDs and whatnot. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Do you know any alternate way or any other Regex that works in these cases?

Comment: did you even bother looking at the link I provided?

Comment: Have you considered this discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/what-are-best-practices-for-validating-email-addresses-in-objective-c-for-ios-2

Comment: Yes. I am looking over the link which you shared. and trying to make some modifications in my regex

Comment: I hv tried some other modifications but those are not working as will.

Comment: Thanks Mark Your answer helped me. I got one solution. I am checking the two regex now. one which is posted in question and one which is posted in comments. if both are true then it works fine in all the cases for me. Thanks for help

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/email.html  useful link

Comment: I guess its enough `\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z` instead of using two regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-(BOOL)emailValidation:(NSString *)str{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx=[emailTest evaluateWithObject:str];

    if (myStringMatchesRegEx == 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

and check email valid or not.

```
if(![self emailValidation:txtEmail.text]){
        [appDelegate showAlert:@"Alert" message:@"Invalid Email Address"];
}
```