# issue in Email validation in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, validation, ipad

I am doing email validation in iOS. I am using following code email validation. This is working fine but it is unable to validate following patterns.

```
.test@gmail.com
test..@gmail.com
test.@tgmail.com
Abc..123@example.com
```

**Code Used**

```
-(BOOL) IsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
    NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];   
}
```

Please tell how to do this?

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/what-are-best-practices-for-validating-email-addresses-in-objective-c-for-ios-2

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex =
@"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
@"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
@"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
@"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
@"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
@"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
@"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Link : [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/what-are-best-practices-for-validating-email-addresses-in-objective-c-for-ios-2)

[image]

Comment: need to test it. brother, yes its shows inValid. but its seldom

Comment: test.5.test@gmail.com sory this

Comment: yes its given True. So its Working Perfect.. @JagveerSingh